# All icon on one gif image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question about the use of icons with .gif extension. I know how to use one by one icon, but how to use the when we have all the icons on a gif?
[image]

This I see in mibew chat, the have all icon on one gif, but when show in chat, they show one by one. 
[image]
Maybe the question is to someone stupid, but I'd like to know how to use this. Thank you

Comment: You mean images sprites? There's some info: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp ;)

Comment: that this is exactly what I need. looked at w3school and I did not see this ... OMG ... Thank you